# How to specify property type when using Cloud Datastore API

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I have this python code snippet for adding a new entity from Google Compute Engine. But this code results in userId being created with an undefined type. How can I specify the type of the property when it is getting created from compute engine?

```
kg = datastore.Entity(key)
try:
  kg.update({
    'userId': userId,
  })
  client.put(kg)
```

Comment: Where does `key` come from?

Comment: key is created from the entity kind. This is perfectly working code so key is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gloud-python` will infer the type of the property from the type of the value you place in the property map.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/blob/master/gcloud/datastore/helpers.py#L303

Comment: But this is not happening in my case. Datastore viewer shows "userId" type as undefined. I also have a List<String> object (not shown in the snippet above) which is being identified as List<blobValue>. Any thing I should be doing before calling put?

Comment: user3787910: you need to supply unicode strings in both userId and list.